Cannot create raster given vector in QGIS
I have a vector which looks like below. I want to create a raster from this, with cells having 1 for roads and 0 for empty areas using QGIS (3.36.3-Maidenhead).
I have tried tools like, gdal:rasterize, etc. without much luck. It ends up giving me a raster with dimensions 1:1, and it certainly is not what I need. It only works if I select "Pixel" for "Output raster size unit" instead of "Georeferenced units" and give manual values like 3600x3600 for resolution.
My ultimate goal is to use gdal:proximity, to come up with a thematic map for proximity to roads (or some other features) by using meters as input. I need a raster output for later usages but I'm struggling on this first step to go there.
I think I'm missing some basic knowledge on cell size / pixel size concepts.

CRS information of the shape file:


Your georeferenced units are decimal degrees, not metres. A rough approximation is 1 degree = 111km at the equator.  So for an approximate 1m output pixel size, you could use 0.000009 (dd).
But since you want to do a distance based analysis later, I recommend you reproject your vector data to a coordinate system (CRS) that uses metres as the units before rasterising. A list of CRSs for Türkiye can be found on epsg.io. Don't use EPSG:3857 Web Mercator, it distorts distances. It was designed for web mapping and is only suitable for visualisation.
For this example I'll use EPSG:5259 TUREF/TM45.  Start by reprojecting. Use Reproject Layer tool, not the Assign Projection tool (which will change the projection definition but not change the coordinates).

Then you can use the Rasterize (vector to raster) tool, set 1 as the value to burn and select georeferenced units and enter the pixel size you want. Below I specified a 10m pixel.  Then QGIS will figure out the number of rows and columns automatically.

